# Finding p% of smallest tensor values - TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am using Python 3.7 and TensorFlow 2.0 and I have the following problem. Within a given tensor of any dimension, if I want to find p% of the smallest weights (where, p can be a user input), how do I do so?

Example:

```
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(3, 2, 2))                                   

x.numpy()                                                               
Out[8]: 
array([[[-0.30938825,  0.40093166],
        [ 1.5417175 , -0.9551434 ]],

       [[-0.7977963 , -2.0784302 ],
        [-1.5039488 , -0.75159657]],

       [[ 1.7954558 ,  0.19909047],
        [-0.2359499 , -2.4791834 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Within the tensor 'x' (of shape: (3, 2, 2)), how can I find say p = 30% of smallest weights? I then plan on removing the p% of smallest weights by setting them to zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [TensorFlow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability)'s [**`stats.percentile`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile):

```
In [5]: import tensorflow_probability as tfp

In [6]: p30 = tfp.stats.percentile(x, q=30.)

In [7]: p30
Out[7]: <tf.Tensor: id=1159, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-0.9551434>

In [8]: tf.where(x <= p30, 0, x)
Out[8]:
<tf.Tensor: id=1108, shape=(3, 2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.30938825,  0.40093166],
        [ 1.5417175 ,  0.        ]],

       [[-0.7977963 ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        , -0.75159657]],

       [[ 1.7954558 ,  0.19909047],
        [-0.2359499 ,  0.        ]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Minimal requirements:

```
tensorflow==2.0
tensorflow-probability==0.7
```

Comment: Ah, I see, you're partially right. tf 2.1 is only required for tfp 0.9. If for some reason you prefer tf 2.0, you can use tfp 0.8 or 0.7. For tf 1.15 however, my code cannot be run on any tfp version.